# how to display excel sheet in asp.net

Tags: c#

I have an excel stored in project folder.
i want to show whole excel,when user click on button showexcel.
once excel open, the user should have write,edit and save options also.

Comment: It's not very clear exactly what you want here.  Do you want the excel sheet to open in the Microsoft Excel client or do you want a way for users to edit the spreadsheet on the web?

Answer (score 0):

How about the new Excel Web App?  You'll have to dig deeper about how to host this.  You can test-drive for free with Windows Live Skydrive.  Its a fantastic product.

general page: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/office-web-apps-FX101825822.aspx

how to host: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee815687.aspx